# How to reference an array of character vectors

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I want to create an array of character vectors like this:

```
'abc1', 'abc12', 'abc9'
```

Two questions:  How do I initialize this, and how do I reference each element?

I want to read a bunch of values from a file and create the array from each line. The file will look like this:

```
abc1 abc12 abc9
```

Once read in, I want to use each character vector like the following:

```
for i in <mumble>
    fprintf(" element = %s\n", <mumble-one-element>)
end
```

(printing is just the easiest way to represent that I want to access each element in the array.)

I'm a newbie to MATLAB and am having a hard time translating array usage to other languages I know.

Comment: [Cell Array](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?lang=en) might match the description. Each element could be accessed by `C{index}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgetl` to read a line from the file and `strsplit` to create a cell array.

Suppose test.txt is your file, which has the following data:

```
abc1 abc12 abc9
abc4 abc5 abc6
```

Read the file line by line and create the corresponding cell array:

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt');

tline = fgetl(fileID);
while ischar(tline)
    cell_array = strsplit(tline);
    for i = 1:length(cell_array)
        fprintf(" element = %s\n", cell_array{i});
    end
    fprintf("\n");
    tline = fgetl(fileID);
end

fclose(fileID);
```

Output:

```
 element = abc1
 element = abc12
 element = abc9

 element = abc4
 element = abc5
 element = abc6
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. My data file contains one string per line not several on each line. I'll look at your suggestion and see if I can make it work in a similar fashion.

Comment: I was just looking at this and noticed you suggestion does not create an array of string vectors. It just separates the strings into single character arrays. But thanks for the ideas.